# How to change datatype of column with data

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's say I have a table `call_log` that has a column named `duration`. Let's further pretend that when I put the table together, I made the mistake of making `duration` a varchar column instead of a number.  Now I can't properly sort on that column. I want to rename the column so I issue...

```
ALTER TABLE call_log MODIFY (duration NUMBER);
```

But I get...

```
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype.
```

My table has been in use and has data! And I don't want to lose the data. How do I modify the column's datatype without losing data?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Create a temporary column with the correct data type, copy the data to the new column, drop the old column, rename the new column to match what the old column was named.

```
ALTER TABLE call_log ADD (duration_temp NUMBER);
UPDATE call_log SET duration_temp = duration;
ALTER TABLE call_log DROP COLUMN duration;
ALTER TABLE call_log RENAME COLUMN duration_temp TO duration;
```

The idea for this answer came from [Oracle's forums](https://community.oracle.com/thread/597075).

Answer (score 6):

the previous solution is excellent, however if you don't want to change the columns orders in call_log table structure, then the following steps are for this:

```
create table temp_call_log  as select * from call_log; /* temp backup table for call_log */
UPDATE call_log SET duration = null;
/*check,... be sure.... then commit*/
commit;
ALTER TABLE call_log MODIFY duration NUMBER;
UPDATE call_log c SET c.duration = (select t.duration from temp_call_log t where t.primarykey_comumn = c.primarykey_column);
/*check,... be sure.... then commit*/
commit;
drop table temp_call_log;
```

note1: change primarykey_comumn with primary key in table call_log.

note2: this solution assumes that your data size is not big.

Comment: Upvote for the comments. I executed the previous solution all in one shot and for some reason it didn't work as expected. I lost all the information of the column with no possible rollback. Next time for sure I'll execute line by line and check to be sure...

Answer (score 4):

The best solution to preserve the original order of columns: create a temp column, copy the data to it, set the original column to null, modify its type, set the data from temp column back to it and drop the temp column:

```
ALTER TABLE call_log ADD duration_temp NUMBER;
UPDATE call_log SET duration_temp = duration;
UPDATE call_log SET duration = NULL;
ALTER TABLE call_log MODIFY duration NUMBER;
UPDATE call_log SET duration = duration_temp;
ALTER TABLE call_log DROP (duration_temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

or some constrains, I could not use the first two solutions:

```
CREATE TABLE call_log_temp AS (SELECT * FROM call_log where rownum = 0);
ALTER TABLE call_log_temp MODIFY duration NUMBER;
INSERT INTO call_log_temp( id, duration, and_all_other_columns, ... )
  SELECT id, duration, and_all_other_columns, ...
  FROM call_log;  
DROP TABLE call_log;    
ALTER TABLE call_log_temp RENAME TO call_log;
```